# Timeseries in R - how to adjust stat_bin (or histogram) to start at a date instead of centering over it?

Tags: r

I've created two plots that are displayed next to each other vertically. The charts themselves are aligned properly, but the problem is that the uppermost plot which uses stat_bin refuses to start AT the first date 30/09. I guess this makes sense as most histograms start 0.5 to the left and end 0.5 to the right, but how can I adjust this? I want the uppermost plot to start at the first date in order for it to align with the second chart. This is my first post by the way, I'm greatful for answers!

```
# Pulling data from SQL
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, Query)
bar <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, Query2)

# Closing SQL objects
rm(Query,Query2,dbhandle)

# Some filtering
res <- res[res$RTC=="S" & res$Category != "Other" & res$RTC =="S",]

# Converting datetime to date
bar$AsPerDate <- as.Date(as.character(bar$AsPerDate), format="%Y-%m-%d")
res$CREATED_ON <- as.Date(as.character(res$CREATED_ON), format="%Y-%m-%d")

# Plot 1
p <-  ggplot(data=res, aes(x=CREATED_ON, color=Category)) +
        stat_bin(data=res[res$Category=="1",],aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step",size=1) +
        stat_bin(data=res[res$Category=="2",],aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step",size=1) +
        stat_bin(data=res[res$Category=="3",],aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step",size=1) +
        stat_bin(data=res[res$Category=="4",],aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step",size=1) +
        theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="grey"), panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour="grey")) +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 day", date_labels = "%d/%m", date_minor_breaks = "1 day",
                     limits = as.Date(c('2016-09-30','2016-10-15')))+
        xlab("Date dd/mm")

# Plot 2
m <-  ggplot(data=bar, aes(x=AsPerDate, y=Value)) +
        geom_line(alpha=1) + geom_point(data=res,aes(x=CREATED_ON,y=REVENUE, color=Category)) +
        theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="grey"), panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour="grey")) +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 day", date_labels = "%d/%m", date_minor_breaks = "1 day",
                     limits = as.Date(c('2016-09-30','2016-10-15'))) +
        xlab("Date dd/mm")

# Combining plots
p1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(m))
maxWidth = unit.pmax(p1$widths[2:3], p2$widths[2:3])
p1$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
p2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
grid.arrange(p1, p2, heights = c(3, 2))
```

[Here is an image-link showing the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OSnO.jpg)

Comment: We don't have `res` or `bar` to reproduce the plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "center" argument of stat_bin as

```
stat_bin(data=res[res$Category=="1",],aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="step",size=1, center = 0.5)
```

I am not sure about the 0.5 value of center so you may try other values as well. "boundary" argument may also be used.